# Elixir - Looping through and adding to map

Tags: enumeration, elixir

I'm rebuilding something in Elixir from some code I built in C#.

It was pretty hacked together, but works perfectly (although not on Linux, hence rebuild).

Essentially what it did was check some RSS feeds and see if there was any new content. This is the code:

```
Map historic (URL as key, post title as value).
List<string> blogfeeds
while true
for each blog in blogfeeds
   List<RssPost> posts = getposts(blog)
   for each post in posts
        if post.url is not in historic
           dothing(post)
           historic.add(post)
```

I am wondering how I can do Enumeration effectively in Elixir. Also, it seems that my very process of adding things to "historic" is anti-functional programming.

Obviously the first step was declaring my list of URLs, but beyond that the enumeration idea is messing with my head. Could someone help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

This is a nice challenge to have and solving it will definitely give you some insight into functional programming.

The solution for such problems in functional languages is usually `reduce` (often called `fold`). I will start with a short answer (and not a direct translation) but feel free to ask for a follow up.

The approach below will typically not work in functional programming languages:

```
map = %{}
Enum.each [1, 2, 3], fn x ->
  Map.put(map, x, x)
end
map
```

The map at the end will still be empty because we can't mutate data structures. Every time you call `Map.put(map, x, x)`, it will return a new map. So we need to explicitly retrieve the new map after each enumeration.

We can achieve this in Elixir using reduce:

```
map = Enum.reduce [1, 2, 3], %{}, fn x, acc ->
  Map.put(acc, x, x)
end
```

Reduce will emit the result of the previous function as accumulator for the next item. After running the code above, the variable `map` will be `%{1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3}`.

For those reasons, we rarely use `each` on enumeration. Instead, we use the functions in [the `Enum` module](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Enum.html), that support a wide range of operations, eventually falling back to `reduce` when there is no other option.

EDIT: to answer the questions and go through a more direct translation of the code, this what you can do to check and update the map as you go:

```
Enum.reduce blogs, %{}, fn blog, history ->
  posts = get_posts(blog)
  Enum.reduce posts, history, fn post, history ->
    if Map.has_key?(history, post.url) do
      # Return the history unchanged
      history
    else
      do_thing(post)
      Map.put(history, post.url, true)
    end
  end
end
```

In fact, a set would be better here, so let's refactor this and use a set in the process:

```
def traverse_blogs(blogs) do
  Enum.reduce blogs, HashSet.new, &traverse_blog/2
end

def traverse_blog(blog, history) do
  Enum.reduce get_posts(blog), history, &traverse_post/2
end

def traverse_post(post, history) do
  if post.url in history do
    # Return the history unchanged
    history
  else
    do_thing(post)
    HashSet.put(history, post.url)
  end
end
```

Comment: Okay awesome, thanks that helps. However, I still don't know how I would handle the checking if an item is new (not in the map) with this approach? Its something happening fairly often and I would prefer to not use something like a DB, although I would if I had to.

It makes a lot of sense though, thank you.

Comment: How about combining two functions from the Enum module: member? and filter.  That way you could compile the list of all items not a member of the existing list then do something.

Comment: How would you add to the filter? Whenever it finds a unique post it adds it to the list (no longer unique) and does a function with it. Is it possible for a function to call itself?

Comment: I have edited the question for a more complete answer!

Comment: Thank you very much @José Valim

Answer (score 0):

This might help too:

```
count_animals_in_area = fn (area, acc) ->
  acc = case Map.has_key?(area, "duck") do
          true ->
            Map.put(acc, "ducks", (acc["ducks"] + area["duck"]))
          false ->
            acc
        end

  acc = case Map.has_key?(area, "goose") do
          true ->
            Map.put(acc, "geese", (acc["geese"] + area["goose"]))
          false ->
            acc
        end

  acc = case Map.has_key?(area, "cat") do
          true -> 
            Map.put(acc, "cats", (acc["cats"] + area["cat"]))
          false ->
            acc
        end

  acc
end

count_animals_in_areas = fn(areas) ->
  acc = %{ "ducks" => 0,
           "geese" => 0,
           "cats" => 0 }
  IO.inspect Enum.reduce areas, acc, count_animals_in_area
end

t1 = [ %{"duck" => 3, "goose" => 4, "cat" => 1},
       %{"duck" => 7, "goose" => 2},
       %{"goose" => 12}]

IO.puts "JEA: begin"
count_animals_in_areas.(t1)
IO.puts "JEA: end"
```

Output:

```
iex(31)> c "count_animals.exs"
JEA: begin
%{"cats" => 1, "ducks" => 10, "geese" => 18}
JEA: end
[]
```

I am just learning Elixir so the above is undoubtedly suboptimal, but, hopefully slightly informative.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to Elixir but here is a cute and simple solution that uses pattern matching and recursion.

```
defmodule YourModule do
   def reduce_list([], reduced) do reduced end

   def reduce_list([first | rest ], reduced) do
      # Do what you need to do here and call the function again 
      # with remaining list items and updated map.
      reduce_list(rest, Map.put(reduced, first, "Done"))
   end
end
```

And call the function with just the list you want to map and an empty map

```
> YourModule.reduce_list(["one", "two", "three"], %{})
  %{"one" => "Done", "three" => "Done", "two" => "Done"}
```