# Create Map on iteration

Tags: elixir

In my module I have a function whose purpose is to generate a Map with some defaults, given immutability in Elixir I couldn't find a proper way of achieving this:

```
defmodule Teams do

  def past_matches() do
    [
      team1: %{team2: %{f: 0, a: 1},  team3: %{f: 1, a: 3}},
      team2: %{team1: %{f: 3, a: 0},  team3: %{f: 2, a: 0}},
    ]
  end

  def initialize(matches, table) do
    Enum.each matches, fn {team, _scores} ->
      Map.put local, team, %{total: 0}
    end
  end

  def run() do
    table = %{}

    past_matches()
    |> initialize(table)
  end

end
```

The idea on `initialize()` is to populate the Map `table` with: `%{team1: %{total: 0}, team2: %{total: 0}, team3: %{total: 0}}`

I understand that the variable `table` is still an empty Map after the piped functions are done but what is the Elixir way of dynamically creating temporary structures like this ?

Relevant: [Elixir - Looping through and adding to map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924170/elixir-looping-through-and-adding-to-map), but I think this is ugly by design and not perfectly suited for maps as the iterable.

Comment: The solution in that answer, i.e. using `Enum.reduce` would be the cleanest way I can think of. Did you try using it? Can you post the code you tried that turned out to be ugly?

Comment: `Enum.reduce matches, local, fn {team, _scores}, acc -> Map.put acc, team, %{total: 0} end`.

Comment: There seems to be a lot of these questions on SO. Basic of immutability is you can't mutate things, which is essentially what you're trying to do with table here.