# Elixir reducing a list and adding to a map

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, elixir, enumeration

I am trying to reduce a list and add some data into a map.
The code is something like this:

```
map = Enum.reduce(1..1000, %{}, fn(x, accumalator) ->(
            calculate a hash of a string
            if condition is fulfilled do
                Map.put(accumalator, string, hash)
            end    
        )end)
```

This is giving me a bad map error saying that `Map.put()` is receiving a `nil` value for the put function.

What I want to do is this: For all the iterations calculate the hash and if some condition is fulfilled regarding the hash add the hash and the nonce into the map. So I want the map to be persistent. Where am I going wrong?
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29924170/elixir-looping-through-and-adding-to-map) also suggests the same thing, but is failing.

Comment: You probably want an else condition in your if for when the condition is not fulfilled. the if expression will return `nil` if the condition is not met and since that is the last expression in the function, that is what gets returned.

Answer (score 4):

The value returned by the function becomes the accumulator in the next iteration. In the function you've defined, if the condition is false, the `if` returns `nil` and in the next iteration `accumulator` is `nil`. What you need to do is add an `else` block and return the unmodified `accumulator` value from that.

```
Enum.reduce(1..1000, %{}, fn(x, accumulator) ->
  ...
  if condition do
    Map.put(accumulator, string, hash)
  else
    accumulator
  end
end)
```